# Constant Rank Theorem without using the Inverse Function Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

### Background

Scanning Wikipedia's article on the Implicit Function Theorem I came across the following comment in the ["See Also"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem#See_also) section:

> Both the implicit function theorem and the inverse function theorem can be seen as special cases of the constant rank theorem.

The article on the Inverse Function Theorem makes a similar claim (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Constant_rank_theorem)):

> The inverse function theorem (and the implicit function theorem) can be seen as a special case of the constant rank theorem, (...) ${}^\text{[11]}$.

**Question 1:** Is this implying that the Constant Rank Theorem can be proved without using the Inverse Function Theorem?

### Main question

If the answer to question 1 is "yes" then

**Question 2:** How can you proof the Constant Rank Theorem without using either the Inverse- or the Implicit Function Theorem?

For the sake of completeness, the Constant Rank Theorem roughly asserts that if the rank of a $C^r$ function $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is constant $k$ on an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x_0$, then there are $C^r$ diffeomorphisms $\alpha,\beta$ such that

$$\alpha \circ f \circ\beta (x_1,...,x_m) = (x_1,...,x_k,0,...,0)$$

near $x_0$. (See for instance John M. Lee, *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, p. 81.)

### Wikipedia's reference

Wikipedia's reference for the second claim is the following:

[11]: Boothby, William M. (1986). *An Introduction to Differentiable Manifolds and Riemannian Geometry*. pp. 46-50.

As you can see from [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSiQq.png), Boothby uses the Inverse Function Theorem in his proof of the Constant Rank Theorem.

Comment: all three theorems (inverse, implicit, constant rank) are equivalent (atleast in finite-dimensions). But the "difficult" part of these implications is that the inverse/implicit function theorem implies constant rank theorem. So any proof which avoids the direct use of IFT (though I haven't seen such a proof) would necessarily have to be more complicated (and I would guess that it would amount to a convoluted way of framing things so as to avoid a direct application of IFT).

Comment: I don't read the statements as implying there is a direct proof of the constant rank theorem.